# identifying time lag duration

Tags: regression, t-test

I have daily observations of fecundity from animals fed 2 different diets (~400 observations, data are integer counts, over-dispersed, left-skewed as many days the animals produce no offspring but some days they produce 1-20+ offspring each).

I expected perhaps a 1-day delay in impact from switching them onto these different diets so the experiment includes 1 loading day (day 0) but actually it looks like it was about 4 days before the effect kicked in, so that observations 1-3 show no effect and observations 4-6 show profound effects. The effects on days 4-6 are canceled out by the high natural variation and similarity through days 1-3.

Is there a principled way to identify this time lag? I don't think I can split them into these two groups and do a t-test since that wasn't my original intent (though I did that for myself and indeed they're very different). I could repeat the experiment with this intent (longer loading phase/count more days after diet change) but isn't that also sort of a form of manipulating the data to get the result I want? Is there a statistical test I can apply to show that at least it was a principled choice to extend the loading period to 3 or 4 days? It seems like an interrupted time series regression makes the same (incorrect, it turns out) assumption I did of near-immediate effect of intervention.